# Const and mutable

Tags: c++

I just came across this code fragment, but I do not understand how it compiles:

```
class temp {
    int value1; 
    mutable int value2;
public:
    void fun(int val) const
    {
        ((temp*) this)->value1 = 10;
        value2 = 10;
    }
};
```

What is the meaning of this line

```
((temp*) this)->value1 = 10;
```

`value1` is getting assigned to 10, without any error. But `value1` is not `mutable`. How does this compile?

Comment: That cast is to make an otherwise-`const temp *` a `temp *`. It is also outright hideous.

Comment: It means whoever wrote this code shouldn't be allowed to write code anymore.

Comment: Technically (potentially) Undefined Behaviour.  If you had `const temp a; a.fun(4);`, then the line you quotes would be modifying an actually const variable.   The assignment to value2 is not because value2 has been declared as `mutable` (and doesn't need nasty C-style or const_cast to make it work...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When a member variable does not have the `mutable` qualifier, you cannot modify it when an object is `const`.

When a member variable has the `mutable` qualifier, you can modify it even when an object is `const`.

Simple example:

```
struct Foo
{
   int var1;
   mutable int var2;
};

const Foo f{};
f.var1 = 10; // Not OK
f.var2 = 20; // OK
```

When you have:

```
void fun(int val) const
{
    ((temp*) this)->value1 = 10;
    value2 = 10;
}
```

you are bypassing the `const`-ness of the object and changing it in a way that you are not supposed to. This is subject to undefined behavior.

As far as the compiler is concerned, that code is equivalent to:

```
void fun(int val) const
{
    temp* ptr = (temp*)this

    // The compiler does not know how you got ptr.
    // It is able to modify value1 through ptr since ptr
    // points to a non-const object.
    ptr->value1 = 10;

    value2 = 10;
}
```

Comment: const Foo f{}; 
you ment const Foo f();

Comment: @Saif Actually he definitely meant `{}` as if he'd used `()` it'd be a function declaration...

Comment: @Saif, `const Foo f{};` constructs a const- object. `const Foo f();` would declare a function `f` that takes no arguments and returns a `const Foo`.

Comment: @R Sahu: Actually `fun` is a `const` member function,  `value1` should not change unless it is made `mutable` or use `const_cast`. How is it possible to change value in `const` fun.

Comment: @Phani, by using an explicit cast, like `((temp*) this)`, you are bypassing the `const`-ness of the object.

Comment: @Phani: It's _not_. The code author used a nasty C-style cast to hack away the `const`ness and lie to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
((temp*) this)->value1 = 10;
```

is said to be "casting away `const`-ness". It basically tells the compiler: Take the `this` pointer (which has the type `temp const*` because we are in a `const` member function of `temp`), *and pretend it were of type `temp*`* (the subexpression `(temp*)this`). Then it instructs the compiler to dereference this pointer of type `temp*` to modify one of its members.

Casting away `const`-ness was how mutable data members were implemented before C++ offered the `mutable` keyword.

As you might have guessed, this is bad practice. It is bad practice, because it could just as well have been expressed with the `mutable` modifier. And it is bad practice because it uses the big gun of a C-style cast where a C++ `const_cast<>` would have sufficed.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn is to start making it a trivial case and see how it goes.

a) if you comment out (*temp) and make it something like
this->value1 = 10;

> error: assignment of data-member ‘temp::value1’ in read-only structure

or

b) if you comment out mutable keyword, you'll get the same error

> error: assignment of data-member ‘temp::value2’ in read-only
>   structure

and if you read above R Sahu provided the right answer about mutable keyword.

If you are confused why can't we modify value with the normal way, remember the function is const and const is a contract that promises we are not supposed to modify or assign any values here (but mutable). so it is basically showing two techniques or hacks to break promise :-)